# Is force stopping an app equivalent to uninstalling it, as far as increasing the performance of a phone is concerned?

Tags: applications, performance, uninstallation, force-stop

Suppose I force stop an app and it stays that way for long. Will this boost the performance of my phone in the same way as uninstalling the app would?

Comment: An app you kill does not "vanish" in thin air. It will still occupy room in your phone's storage, just as a pile o' junk.

Comment: What if the app is installed in external storage? In that case the space it will occupy will be tiny, and being forced stopped, it should not occupy background space and behave as good as being uninstalled.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some cases, yes, if your performance issue is not caused by low storage space. The improvement may be temporary, however, as apps can be restarted if they are registered for certain actions or events.

Comment: Quite synthetic, but you're addressing the issue. There's just a thing to remember, though: if an app, as you said, is programmed to restart its services, then killing them will only be a waste of battery.

Comment: @death mask salesman: This is why i stated in my question - "Suppose I force stop an app and it stays that way for long." I have some apps that simply die when i kill them, so i was wondering if they were as good as dead or not.